# Definition of the ring of global functions on an algebraic variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am currently reading R. Hartshorne, Algebraic Geometry, Springer, 1977. On page 16, he uses the term "ring of global functions", denoted $\mathcal{O}(Y)$, where $Y$ is a variety. I do not find a definition of this term in this book or elsewhere. How is the ring of global functions defined here?

Comment: this is the ring of regular functions $Y\to k$, where $k$ is the algebraically closed field over which $Y$ is defined; see page 3 for the definition

Comment: How does $\mathcal{O}(Y)$ become a subring of $K(Y)$, the function field with its elements the rational functions? Does $K(Y)$ include maps with singularities, plainly speaking, which would then make sense $\mathcal{O}(Y)$ being a subring of $K(Y)$?

Comment: $K(Y)$ is the total ring of fractions of $\mathcal{O}(Y)$.

Comment: a concrete description of $K(Y)$ is as equivalence classes of pairs $(U,f)$, where $U\subseteq Y$ is a non-empty open subset and $f:U\to k$ is a regular function. $(U,f)$ and $(V,g)$ are equivalent if there is some non-empty open $W\subseteq U\cap V$ such that $f|_W=g|_W$. then $\mathcal{O}(Y)$ embeds into $K(Y)$ via the map taking a regular function $f:Y\to k$ to the equivalence class of the pair $(Y,f)$

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom looks like this could be an answer to me - please consider recording it as such below.